# jPanelMenu is breaking AngularJS ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am using [jPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/) in a [ToDo application](https://github.com/brettof86/do) for the left side menu. I have created a directive to apply the jPanelMenu to the appropriate elements.

Everything is working as expected except there is a nested ng-repeat with a nested ng-click inside of the element that gets reassigned with jPanelMenu.

```
<jpmenu>
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories"> 
            <a href="#" ng-click="setFilterCategory(category)">{{ category }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</jpmenu>
```

The ng-click event is not firing in the created jpanel menu.

Notes:

- jPanelMenu coppies the jpmenu element and applies it's styles to it, not using the original dom elements
- The original DOM elements still exist and they are "display:none;"
- the class ng-scope is missing from the recreated jpanel menu element
- The ng-click element fires properly on the original DOM element if I unhide it and click it, but the recreated elements do NOT fire at all.

I've added a timeout to the directive to delay the jpanel menu recreation (to wait for angular to finish it's other directives first) but that didn't help

Here is a jsfiddle example of exactly what's going on (THIS FIDDLE DOES NOT RUN IN CHROME BECAUSE OF CROSS SITE SECURITY): http://jsfiddle.net/47PXj/

If you click the unhidden original menu items in the jsfiddle you'll see the text updating, but if you click the menu items in the left menu they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bootstrap your app. Try this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: It was on the html tag in the application and I just forgot to copy it over to the jsfiddle, that's not the culprit. Even with that in the jsfiddle it's still broken.